# Use .slidetoggle to make div expand and collapse again on page load

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Hi guys i have a div box with text which is hidden until you click a button and then it .slideToggles open to its height and then when you click again it toggles closed.

Now what i would like to do is on page load for the box to expand and then collapse again and stop (not auto repeat ), so that people see that there is content hidden away and to click the button. Can anyone help with this?? I'm not big into jQuery.

Here's what i've got.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#page-information").hide();
                $(".info-tab").toggle(function() {
                    $(".info-tab").addClass("info-active");
                    }, function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("info-active");
                }); 
                $(".info-tab").click(function() {
                    $("#page-information").slideToggle('slow');
                });
            });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I thought you could just do two slidetoggles back to back at the beginning but obvioulsy not.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Not everyone watches a page as it loads. Wouldn't a tooltip or some sort of box pointing to it that they can close work better for your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#page-information").slideDown('slow', function(){
        setTimeout("$('#page-information').slideUp('slow');", 500);
    });
    $(".info-tab").toggle(function() {
        $(".info-tab").addClass("info-active");
        }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("info-active");
    });
    $(".info-tab").click(function() {
        $("#page-information").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/yRqqq/2/

Comment: Hey man!! you are a lovely human being! that's great! on first page load you see it slide down and then back up but then on every other page after that it starts expanded and then collapses. Is it still possible to force the slide down before up after first page load? Thanks so much Nick!! very very grateful.

Comment: Just to expand Nick. Your code on jsfiddle does it exactly where as mine seems to load open and then collapse. thanks

Comment: Just taking a stab in the dark but that could be your CSS for the #page-information element. If you open up that JSFiddle I made and change the #page-information elements css from: 'display:none;' to 'display:block;' you'll notice that the slideDown doesn't execute. This is because slideDown only works on elements that aren't being displayed. When we execute the slideDown on a displayed element, jQuery see this as being completed - so it just executes the callback function - which is our slideUp. If this doesn't fix your issue - Please post html and css your using.

Comment: Hey Alex- don't forget to accept which answer worked for you (if any did) - helps others who may be looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".info-tab").toggle(function() {
       $(".info-tab").addClass("info-active");}
   });

   setTimeout(function(){
       $(".info-tab").toggle(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("info-active");
          $("#page-information").slideToggle('slow');
       });
    }, 1000);



        $("#page-information").hide();
            $(".info-tab").toggle(function() {
                $(".info-tab").addClass("info-active");
                }, function () {
                $(this).removeClass("info-active");
            }); 
            $(".info-tab").click(function() {
                $("#page-information").slideToggle('slow');
            });
        });
```