# slideup slidedown issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

i have a little question, regarding to slideup and slidedown, the problem is in slideup actually, once i click the link the content is sliding down, and thats ok, but when im trying to close this slide, it slidesup and slidedown automatically, i mean it can't be closed once it is opened :) anyway, hope everything will be clear after i show u the code:

```
    $items = $('#accordion a.item');
    $items.click(function () {
        $items.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');  
        return false;
    });
```

and html:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item">BANKS</a>
        <ul>BLA BLA BLA</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item">PETROL</a>
        <ul>BLA BLA BLA</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

all i want is to make it able to be closed.

and thank you all for the helping me and sparing some time, i really appreciate it!

Comment: Hiya so all you want is to slide up and down when your anchor heading is clicked? just checking before I post my answer! I might have a jsfiddle for your question as demo, cheerios!

Comment: @tats_init yes, but if i click another link the previous one will close, slideup i mean. but if i click the opened link it should close

Comment: Saweet gimme 2 mins I have a solution for you! cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit man! :) positive intentions are welcome =3

Comment: `code`
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $items = $('#accordion a.item');
   $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
   $items.click(function () {
    $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
    if ($(this)[0] != $('.selected')[0]) {
       $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');  
    }
    $items.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
   }); 
  }); 
 </script>

Comment: @barts u can change ur answer, and i will accept it ;)

Comment: lol - chaos :P anyways I have written a compact code for you, take a look, write now playing with the clicking again and close version, have a nice one! cheerios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slidedown after your slideup

```
    $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');
```

when the selectors for both are equal, it will slide up and down.

You can try to skip the slidedown for the clicked item if it was open when clicked

EDIT

Javascript code to be changed slightly

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $items = $('#accordion a.item');
        $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
        $items.click(function () {
            $('#accordion li').children('ul').slideUp('slow'); 
            if ($(this)[0] != $('.selected')[0]) {
               $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('slow');  
               $items.removeClass('selected');
               $(this).addClass('selected');
            } else {
               $items.removeClass('selected');
            }
            return false;
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: if (!$(this).is('.selected')) {
  //slide down here
}

Note that you must move around adding and removing the selected class too

EDIT had a mistake in the selector

Comment: thank you very much! u answered my question, but how do i remove the class, after i close it?! :)

Comment: 'selected' is just a class name attached to the tag. it is still there when you close it. I recommend you use google chrome or safari developer tools. Then you can set breakpoints in the javascript, and inspect the html. It takes a bit time to get used to the tools but it is very useful to see what;s happening under the hood.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I get what you mean. Updated the code accordingly (not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Hiya Here you go **demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/uetGd/29/

Fixed the other issue you can improve it more : http://jsfiddle.net/uetGd/39/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item">BANKS</a>
        <ul>BLA BLA BLA</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item">PETROL</a>
        <ul>BLA BLA BLA</ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$('.item')
    .ready(accordionSlideUpDown) // on ready
    .click(accordionSlideUpDown); // on click


function accordionSlideUpDown(){
    $('#accordion').children().children('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();   
}
​
```

**OR** Edit

```
$('#accordion').children().children('ul').slideToggle();
var previous = "";

$('.item')
    .ready(accordionSlideUpDown) // on ready
    .click(accordionSlideUpDown); // on click


function accordionSlideUpDown(){
    var newval = $(this).text();

    $('#accordion').children().children('ul').slideUp();

    if (newval != previous){
         $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    }
      previous = $(this).text();                       
}

​
```

Comment: this is having the same slideup/slidedown problem if some items are added

Comment: gimme 1 more minute updating my answer LOLz! :)

Comment: @Tats_innit im waiting for you :)

Comment: @venom done what you wanted see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uetGd/39/ I am off to sleep soon now late at my part of globe :)) cheerios

Comment: @venom done man just pinged you :) but too late you accepted other answer damn; owe me a pizza now! have a good one!

Comment: @Tats_innit : +1 for your answer

Comment: @Tats_innit, thank you, now ur code is longer )) can u write the same thing with adding and removing class 'selected'?

Comment: @barts lol cheers man! venom play round with slide toggle I reckon you can make it much awesome,!

Comment: @Tats_innit oh! :) bart s, was again one step forward ^.^

Comment: @venom yeah I reckon if you need class go with what bart did for you; if you purely want non class oriented toggle sliding then take a look around slide toggle or might be this give you idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433552/use-slidetoggle-to-make-div-expand-and-collapse-again-on-page-load ; its bit late at this end so will bail out soon.  :) Nice to talk to you both guys! have a good one!